# Wadler's paper: How is a tuple a function?

Tags: haskell

In reading Wadler's original paper [Monads for Functional Programming](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/monads.html) (1992), I feel as if I'm getting it, *but*, in the non-monadic description of a state handler, he shows the proto-monadic description of a State:

```
type M a = State -> (a, State)
eval :: Term -> M Int
eval (Con a) x = (a, x)
```

And it stopped making sense again.  How am I supposed to read this? As I understand it, this says that eval takes an int and a state and returns a function that takes a state and returns a new pair (Int, State)

But... how does (a, x), which, if I'm reading this right is a tuple of a value and a state, *is-a* "function that takes a state and returns a new pair (Int, State)"?

Comment: Check the signature again - `eval :: Term -> M Int` does not directly say that `eval` takes a `State`! It only takes it once, as expanded from the `M` type alias, as opposed to twice, which your description makes it sound like.

Comment: @jww This question is specifically about the Haskell implementation of this concept. The answer/explanation of the problem the asker is having is particular to the Haskell programming language, so I think that it belongs here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @jww Leaving whether or not this belongs on SO aside (I agree with David here though), this absolutely does _not_ belong on CS.

Comment: @Elf (and others) - "off-topic" was a bad call on my part. Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expand the type synonym: `Term -> M Int` is equivalent to `Term -> State -> (Int, State)`.

Alternately, think of the function definition as `eval (Con a) = \x -> (a, x)`.

Comment: I went through both exercises, as you recommended.  I *think* I get it.  The substitutions made sense, at any rate, but I'm still struggling with the whole idea of how I get the results of the calculator's expression back out at the end.